# With Install4j how do I load vmoptions from the users home directory on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

We build our software using Install4j and would like to use the built in code signing. However, our software must also allow the user to modify the memory settings (eg. Xmx) but on Mac OS this will break the code signing because it touches Info.plist.

Is there any way to redirect the vmoptions to the users home directory on Mac OS so we can modify them there? Or perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: You could try using the `JAVA_OPTS` environment varaible

Answer (score 0):

In the VM options file you can add a line

```
-include-options [another vmoptions file]
```

You would have to modify the vmoptions file in the installer so that [another vmoptions file] is an absolute path in the home directory.

Comment: The mac os launcher doesn't read vmoptions files though. From the install4j documentation: 

For GUI launchers on Mac OS X, the VM options are stored in a file called Info.plist inside the application bundle. The "Add VM options" action described below handles these platform-specific differences. .vmoptions files are not supported on Mac OS X.

Comment: If you use Java 7+, they are supported. I'll check where it says that in the documentation and correct it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. For Java 6, the Apple stub is used and there is no native code from install4j in that case that could handle the .vmoptions file. For Java 7, install4j supplies its own stub for launching Java.